# Concentration of sequence of integrals

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I hope my question has not been asked elsewhere in this forum :).

Today, I have a question concerning to the concentration of sequence of integrals. For simplicity, let $\{f_n\}_n$ be a sequence of smooth functions in, for example, $[-1,1]$. Assume for any $\rho \in (0,1)$ arbitrary small but fixed that
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\rho}^{\rho} f_n(x) dx \geqslant 1.$$
Can we conclude that
$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\frac 1n}^{\frac 1n} f_n(x) dx >0?$$

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think so: given $f_{n}$ with the condition of the first integral satisfied,  if we define $g_{n}=f_{n}$ if $n=2k$ and  $g_{n}=0$ if $n=2k+1$ then $\liminf $ of the integral is zero but the $\limsup $ is unchanged.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that I am interested in the case f_n are non-negative, non-trivial :).

Comment: $g_{n}=f_{n}$ if n is even and $g_{n}(x)=x^{n}$ if n is odd.